# Information to the snippet: "scp user@hostb:file user@hostc:"

Tags: scp

*Suppose you have root access in an unknown server. You want to copy a file from the server to your local machine. [Source](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/809/scp-file-from-hostb-to-hostc-while-logged-into-hosta) of the snippet in the title.*

**Challenge:** copy to a file from the unknown server, where you have root rights, to your local machine

```
ROOT+SERVER+FILE+Unknow    ----    Commands?    --->     FILE+LOCAL+YOUR+COMP
                                   scp? how?
```

Please, give some example.

Comment: Related question is here: http://superuser.com/questions/15182/homeserver-for-the-command-scp-userserverfile-localhostservermycomp. Sorry for wasting comment space, but my rep is not enough for two hyperlinks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you cannot copy something to an *unknown* server. You will have to know its name and you will have to have an account on that machine.

The link you gave tells you how to copy something from server X to server Y issuing the command on your local machine.

EDIT:

If I understand you correctly, you want to find out on what machine you are.

You could use the `hostname -f` command that should give you the complete hostname. But to copy something from that machine to another server, you don't need that information, you just do the following:

```
scp file user@server:
```

Comment: but even with known servers or a server and my local machine, how can I get the information to the snippet?

Comment: I really don't understand. What kind of information are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you! I chose your answer because of you being the first with the simplest example. Unfortunately, my rep is not enough for upvotes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

scp works just like cp or rcp, SOURCE is the first argument, DESTINATION is the second.

- Copy file from a server to current directory on local machine

  scp user@server:/path/file .
- Copy file from a server to a different server

  scp user@server:/path/file user@different_server:/path/file

Answer (score 1):

Suposing you know the name of the host, you can do

Copying **to** local machine **from** remote server:
`scp user@remote_addr:file /local/path/`
or
`scp user@remote_addr:file .`
or
`scp user@remote_addr:file /local/path/file`

Copy **from** local machine **to** remote server:
`scp file user@remote_addr:.`
or
`scp file user@remote_addr:/remote/path/`
or
`scp file user@remote_addr:/remote/path/file`

One could use scp even to copy local to local (like `cp`):
`scp file /local/path/file2`

EDIT:
If you are logged in the remote server, consider remote_addr the address of you computer and de unknown server the local machine. Is that what you want?