# Homeserver for the command "scp user@server:file localhost@server:mycomp/"?

Tags: scp, home-server

**Problem:** to get the cammond "scp file user@server:" [(source)](https://superuser.com/questions/15149/information-to-the-snippet-scp-userhostbfile-userhostc/15153#15153) work vice versa. I need a server on my local machine so I can copy files to-and-fro like:

```
ROOT+SERVER+FILE      <----    Commands?    --->     FILE+LOCAL+YOUR+COMP
                               scp? how?             turn it to a server?
```

I want to use the command:

```
scp user@server:file me@my_local_server_on_my_comp:
```

Comment: You don't need an sshd server running to scp a file from a remote system. I strongly suggest reading 'man scp' and 'man ssh' on your system so you understand these commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument is the "destination," which can be a server and a path, or just a path.

`scp file user@server:newfile` will copy "file" to the server as "newfile"

`scp user@server:file newfile` will copy "file" from the server as "newfile" <-- This is what you are looking for.

`scp user@server1:file user@server2:newfile` will copy "file" from server1 to server2 as "newfile"

Comment: He doesn't have to specify a name for the file on his local machine.  'scp user@server:file . ' will copy the file to the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy a remote **file** from the **server** to your local machine with,

```
localmachine prompt> scp user@server:/path/to/file /local/path/
```

- This assumes you have a **user** named login on the server,
- It will ask you for password to **user** on **server** if you do not have public key authentication setup.
- It will copy the remote **file** to your local disk at `/local/path`
- It will get the file from the absolute path `/path/to/` on the **server**